# Update existing Object in COS

Tags: ibm-cloud-storage

I have created a nodeJS app that calls the .putObject() API to successfully add an object (file) to an existing bucket as explained here:
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/libraries/node.html#using-node-js

That works fine and uploads and creates the new object successfully.  However, at a later date we wish to update some Metadata{} about that object.  I see that you can specify this at the .putObject() as a parameter, but there appears to be no .updateObject() API - is that correct?
https://ibm.github.io/ibm-cos-sdk-js/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property

If I call the .putObject() API again with the Metadata{}, it adds that information but blows away the Body content, so the 6Mb file becomes 0kb.  Is the only way to do this to download the object content, add the Metadata{} and then re-upload everything again?

Or is there a different method I can use to just update the Metadata{} and leave the original object (file) as-is?

*I appreciate that one of the answers will be "use a database to store linked metadata", that's fine, but I'd like the answer to the above question rather than a deviation into that discussion, if possible.*

Answer (score 0):

You can apply new metadata to an object by copying it and specifying the new metadata.

Mike